# Model dialogue open only once

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

My `model` dialog with a partial view only an be accessible once, after closing its not opening.
Appreciate your help.

**Button :**

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-url="@Url.Action("Create","POPM_Trn_IOU")" id="btnCreateAsset">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add Asset
 </button>
```

**Model :**

```
<div class="glyphicon-modal-window" id="createAssetModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="CreateAssetModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div id="createAssetContainer"></div>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
  $("#btnCreateAsset").on("click", function () {
      var url = $(this).data("url");
      $.get(url, function (data) {
          $('#createAssetContainer').html(data);                   
          $('#createAssetModal').modal('show');                                
      });
  });
```

Comment: Checked , debugger tool if you are using chorme F12. See Error.

Comment: $(document).on('click', '#btnCreateAsset', function () {
 var url = $(this).data("url");
      $.get(url, function (data) {
          $('#createAssetContainer').html(data);                   
          $('#createAssetModal').modal('show');                                
      });
});

Comment: Use above code. .

Comment: Thanks Asif  i tried your code but the result is same. same error model is not a function is still appear in console after the first load.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery clash and  jQuery.noConflict(); save the day. thanks all.

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnCreateAsset', function () {
            var url = $(this).data("url"); $.get(url, function (data) {
                $('#createAssetContainer').html(data);

                event.preventDefault();
                jQuery.noConflict();
                $('#createAssetModal').modal('show');
            });
        });
```